# symfony: custom Validator does not work with embedRelation?

Tags: php, symfony1

I am using the symfony embedRelation method to embed forms.The code is like this:

public function configure(){
//......

$this->embedRelation('Foos as foos');

$this->getEmbeddedForm('foos')->mergePostValidator(new MenuValidatorSchema());
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
this does not work.
}

Comment: StackOverflow is a community and you need to respect some rulse. When somebady answers your question, accept this answer and close the question, don't leave it as that.

Answer (score 3):

When embeding forms in Symfony, the top-level form keeps track of everything. The widget schema, validator schema, defaults, etc. of the embedded form are no longer directly used. You can see what's happening in `sfForm::embedForm`.

Note that in this case, since it's a post validator, it's perfectly acceptable to add it to the top-level form, i.e.:

```
$this->mergePostValidator(new MenuValidatorSchema());
```

If you want the validator schema on the embedded form and it has no current post validator, you can simply do:

```
$this->validatorSchema['foos']->setPostValidator(new MenuValidatorSchema());
```

If it has an existing one, you'll have to turn them into an sfValidatorAnd, doing something like:

```
$this->validatorSchema['foos']->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorAnd(array(
    'validators' => array(
         $this->validatorSchema['foos']->getPostValidator(),
         new MenuValidatorSchema()
    )
)));
```

The syntax of that last option is just one reason why setting post validators on the top-level form is the preferred option when available.